# Empty Content in Bootstrap Grid Cell causes cell to not render

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Suppose I have a bootstrap grid:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">First Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">John</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Last Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Smith</div>    
</div>
```

This works fine.

However, if the second cell is empty, then the second cell isn't rendered at all:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">First Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Last Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Smith</div>    
</div>
```

This causes unexpected wrapping behavior when there are multiple rows:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">First Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Last Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Smith</div>    
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">First Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Timothy</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Last Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Barton</div>    
</div>
```

The problem seems to be that when the content is empty, the cell doesn't seem to be rendered at all.  I know this can be fixed by adding a `&nbsp;` when the content is empty, but I'm looking for a less obtrusive solution - preferably using Bootstrap or CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that's sort of the nature of block level elements in HTML. If there's no content, and they don't have a min-height set, they collapse.

One workaround would be to do this:

```
.col-sm-3:empty::after{
  content: ".";
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Great! Works, but i'm curious... What does the content: "." do?

Comment: Well, "content" just means add this HTML to the element. You could change it to: `content: "I'm some awesome content!"` if you wanted to.

Comment: Also, remember to buy a lot of alcohol if you need to still support IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

use offset  class.

like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">First Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 offset"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Last Name</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">Smith</div>    
</div>
```

This will create a void space of 3 grid cells

Check : http://www.bootply.com/bj8EUvwPS6

Comment: There's already a horizontal space. "offset" doesn't do anything. The problem is when you resize the browser and the columns wrap, then there's no *vertical* space.

Comment: Oh...,,so can we use something like .top-buffer { margin-top:10px; } where it doesn't have to be 10px, it can be any value you like.

Comment: Sure, but I think the idea is that the OP doesn't want to have to worry about changing his HTML based on whether there is data or not. In other words, he doesn't want to say: `if empty then do XYZ` he want it to just work without having to think about it. You can imagine if there were 500 columns having if statements around each one (with whatever language he is using to generate the HTML) would be less than ideal.

Comment: aaahhhh,,i get it now :)

Comment: Thanks :) ,,what i normally do is use something like <div class="control-group"> whenever i have such condition...But iguess your answer seems much simpler

Answer (score 1):

You can use JQ to add space in each cell which doesn't have content

```
$('.col-sm-3').each(function (index, elem) {
  if($(elem).text().length === 0) {
    $(elem).html('&nbsp;');
  }
});
```

http://www.bootply.com/KIUjqVKQrw